# UIScrollView frame y coordinate goes 20 pixels up when content is updated

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Original view, at top position:
[image]

View after new content has been added, at top position (The view moved 20 pixels upwards)
[image]

View after scrolling a little extra to the top (Like when you refresh pulling the content down)
[image]

So when I add a new view inside this view and update the sizes and everything to make it look correct, I still have an unsolvable thing. Which makes the scrollview start from 20 pixels above the normal point in y axis.

I tried fixing this with adding +20 pixels to the scrollView frame. It works ok when I make only 1 update, if I make several updates now the scrollView starts a lot of pixels below of where it actually should start. I tried this with locking the +20 addition to only happen on the first time, it didn't work. Plus the scrollview messes up completely in new views too.

I don't have storyboard or xib. The project is full programmatically developed.

By the way I checked every variable in scollView, self.view, cardView that I could think of that would affect this. The problem is none of their frame variables are changing in any way. But they act like something changed and I just couldn't figure out what.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false

    createScrollView()
}
```

//How I created the SV in viewdidload

```
func createScrollView() {
    scrollView.frame = self.view.frame
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.sizeToFit()
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: cardWidth, height: 100)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
}
```

//How I create a view inside my scrollview

```
func makeNewCard() {
    var newCard = CardView()
    newCard.createCard(sender: self)

    gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("cardWasDragged:"))
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    newCard.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: cardWidth, height: newCard.frame.height + CGFloat(50 + 64))
    scrollView.addSubview(currentCardView)
}
```

//Creating my view inside another View class

```
func createCard(#sender: CardVC) {
    frame = CGRect(x: ScreenWidth/15, y: 64, width: cardWidth, height: cardHeight)
    contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    userInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

//Adding about 20-50 pixels of new content in the view

```
func newContent() {
    var extraHeight = newHeight

    frame = CGRect(x: ScreenWidth/15, y: 64, width: cardWidth, height: frame.height + extraHeight)

    senderView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: cardWidth, height: senderView.scrollView.contentSize.height + extraHeight - 20) //Had to put -20, I guess I will remove the -20 after this is fixed     
}
```

Comment: automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false in view controller

Comment: already have that, editing the question

Answer (score 1):

Probably because of ViewController property(Under Top Bars) I had the same issue.

In code

```
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
```

Try to change it to:

[image]

Please replay if it work? if not I will try to think on something else who can cause it.
Good luck

Comment: I do not use storyboard, therefore I do not have this UI. But I do have the block of code:     self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

Comment: I do not have a nib so no idea what to do about that one.

Comment: added in viewdidload and didn't work. i don't think i have problem with the bars

Comment: I didn't think so to but I had the same problem and this line fixed it..
anyhow I'm trying to think what can cause it, if I'll think on something I will reply...